# Does the purchased double XP and VIP XP bonus stack in Gears of War Judgement ?

Tags: gears-of-war-judgment

I just found out that you can purchase game packs of double xp and if you have the VIP pass (season pass) more XP is awarded when you play under the VIP menu.   That sparked the question, if I get both, does the double XP and VIP bonus XP stack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The double XP is listed as a separate item, but the higher vip score is just each thing is worth more, so it appears that they can stack.

Answer (score 0):

On the VIP list you are earning more points than on the normal list. However, it doesn't display that you are earning double XP like when you buy double XP and it tells you how many you have left. So you are getting x4 XP nice!